# Maintain Formatting between Confluence and Jira (Create Jira Issue Micro )

Tags: jira, confluence

I am trying to integrate Product Requirements from `Confluence` with `Jira`.

Using `Jira` issue macro in confluence to create multiple `Jira` issues.

But in the `Confluence` product requirement table the requirements are listed as a bulleted numbers, but I don't see the same format in `Jira` issues.

Please refer the below examples for more details:

- [Confluence Page - Product Requirements Table with Bullet
  formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXpme.png)
- [Jira Issue Page - No Formatting for the same requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXpme.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can have better experience using C4J Addon, which show the user the exact Confluence content directly in the Jira issues.
You can try it for free at: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222263/c4j-content-display-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview

Best wishes,
Y